# Integrating $\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta \cos^2(2\alpha)}$ with respect to $\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm having some issues with the following integral

$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta \cos^2(2\alpha)}d\theta$$

My attempt is as follows, substitute $u=\tan\theta$(but this gives infinite bounds)
So $d\theta=\frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}du$, substituting both $\theta$ and $d\theta$ gives

$$\int_{\tan(\frac{-\pi}{2})}^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}\frac{1}{1+u^2 \cos^2(2\alpha)}du$$

This time substituting $v=u\cos(2\alpha)$, $du=\frac{1}{\cos(2\alpha)}dv$, which gives

$$\int_{\tan(\frac{-\pi}{2})\cos(2\alpha)}^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(2\alpha)}\frac{1}{1+v^2}dv=\bigg{[} \arctan (v)\bigg{]}_{\tan(\frac{-\pi}{2})\cos(2\alpha)}^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(2\alpha)}$$

I don't think I've made any mistakes in my substitutions, but I'm still wondering how to get past the infinite bounds, since $\tan(\pi/2)=\infty$ and $\tan(-\pi/2)=-\infty$

Comment: what exactly is the problem? looks fine to me

Comment: Just as an aside, there was no need for the second substitution. $\cos^2 2\alpha$ is just a constant, so your integral is of the form $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 +(ax)^2}$ where the constant $a = \cos 2\alpha$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "proper" way to deal with infinite bounds is to write down the integral as :

$$\lim_{\beta \to -\infty} \int_{\beta}^0 \frac{1}{1+u^2 \cos^2(2\alpha)} \, \mathrm{d}u + \lim_{\gamma \to \infty} \int_0^{\gamma} \frac{1}{1+u^2 \cos^2(2\alpha)} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

and then work with limits throughout. Most of the time, we circumvent the lengthy limit notation and write down the *improper* integral the way you have. This should lead you to $$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\cos^2 2\alpha}} + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\cos^2 2\alpha}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\cos^2 2\alpha}}$$

Comment: In my solution I get that that the answer would be the total area under the curve $\arctan x$, but how did you get that answer to be $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\cos^2 2\alpha}}$

Answer (score 2):

You were very close to the correct answer, but dropped the term $\frac{1}{\cos 2\alpha}$ in the last substitution.  As @zainpatel suggested, we need to be careful with the integration limits here.

In fact, the last integral in the posted question, corrected for the omitted multiplicative term $\frac{1}{\cos 2\alpha}$, and taking care of the sign of $\cos 2\alpha$, can be evaluated as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\cos 2\alpha}\int_{-\text{sgn}(\cos 2\alpha)\infty}^{\text{sgn}(\cos 2\alpha)\infty}\frac{1}{1+v^2}dv&=\left.\left(\frac{1}{\cos 2\alpha}\arctan(v)\right)\right|_{-\text{sgn}(\cos 2\alpha)\infty}^{\text{sgn}(\cos 2\alpha)\infty}\\\\
&=\pi\frac{\text{sgn}(\cos 2\alpha)}{\cos 2\alpha}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{|\cos 2\alpha|}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice,

$\color{blue}{\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x) dx\iff f(-x)=f(x)}$, Now we have 
$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta\cos^22\alpha}$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta\cos^22\alpha}$$ Now, let $\tan \theta=t \implies \sec^2\theta d\theta=dt$, &

$t\to 0 \ as \ \theta\to 0$,  $t\to \infty \ as \ \displaystyle \theta\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ ($\alpha$ being constant)
$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2\cos^22\alpha}$$ 
$$=\frac{2}{\cos^22\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sec^22\alpha+t^2}$$ 
$$=\frac{2}{\cos^22\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{(\sec 2\alpha)^2+t^2}$$ 
$$=\frac{2}{\cos^22\alpha}\frac{1}{\sec2\alpha}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sec2\alpha}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}$$ 
$$=\frac{2}{\cos 2\alpha}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\infty \right)-\tan^{-1}(0)\right]$$ $$=\frac{2}{\cos 2\alpha}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$ $$=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{\cos 2\alpha}}$$